# Configuration file is not well-formed XML

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, codecharge

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

The Config Source section reads:

```
35:     <add key="Miser_Rep_ETL_testString" value="/>
36:     <add key="Miser_Rep_ETL_testServer" value="MSSQLServer"/>
37:     <add key="Miser_Rep_ETL_testDateFormat" value="yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss"/>
```

with line 36 being highlighted in red.

The `web.config` file was created, along with rest of the project, by CodeCharge Studio 5 (set to generate ASP.NET C#), so I don't believe there is something wrong with the XML. Since this is a new server (IIS 7.5), I suspect something else may (IIS) may be misconfigured. The same project works fine if deployed as classic ASP. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in line 35:

```
<add key="Miser_Rep_ETL_testString" value="/>
```

The `value` attribute is malformed and should be:

```
<add key="Miser_Rep_ETL_testString" value=""/>
```

Note that I simply added a `"` to enclose an empty attribute value.

Comment: I am surprised... maybe I'm doing something wrong when building that connection in CodeCharge. It worked (I am getting a different error now :) Thanks!!